# How to copy a sheet with multiple drop down lists and not loss the data with in the list?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Within Excel how do I move or copy a sheet with multiple drop down lists from one workbook to another? When I try using the Move or Copy feature, the values in the various drop down lists do not carry forward.

I have tried coping the data validation source from the original spreadsheet (`='Picklist Create Ren Mths'!$A$2:$A$13`) to the newly created one and this is the message I am receiving:

> This type of reference cannot be used in a Data Validation formula. Change the reference to a single cell, or use the reference with a worksheet function, such as =SUM(A1:E5).

Comment: Could you please re-create your scenario from scratch? Start from blank sheet and create field with drop down list constructed from some short list of values. For me, copying or moving in such a test worked fine between worksheets or workbooks in Excel 2013. Field with drop down list was usable as before.

Comment: I have tried coping the data validation source from the original spreadsheet (='Picklist Create Ren Mths'!$A$2:$A$13) to the newly created one and this is the message I am receiving....."This type of reference cannot be used in a Data Validation formula.  Change the reference to a single cell, or use the reference with a worksheet function, such as =SUM(A1:E5).

Comment: Welcome to the [SU] site. Giving all necessary details can speed up resolution of your issue. I pasted your recent comment into your question. This way you can update your question any time using **edit** link below it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Replace local range reference with global.

Try changing cell your reference into reference to *global* named range:

1. Give some name, e.g. `PickListSrc1` to your range `'Picklist Create Ren Mths'!$A$2:$A$13`
2. Change your data validation criteria from 
   `='Picklist Create Ren Mths'!$A$2:$A$13`
   to `=PickListSrc1` (the name you created)

For further details, please check [official help on drop-down lists](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b) which recommends using named ranges (and yes, they are global).

Local ranges contain reference to worksheet while global ones don't. [The same problem](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/711963-problems-excel-2010-data-validation.html) was already experienced by someone else and changing reference in the above sense helped. (Please note that the above link refers to page 1 of **2**. Resolution is on page **2**.)